# How to log in across websites like Google does?

Tags: php, session, authentication

Have you noticed how you can log in at www.google.com and then open www.youtube.com or www.blogger.com and guess what - you are already logged in without the need to login by entering your username and password. So by just logging in one of Google's websites, you are automatically logged in all of them. That is pretty cool! But how did they do that? As far as I know PHP sessions only work for sub domains or domains.

I also have multiple websites and I would like to make it so that when a user logs in one of them then he is automatically logged in the other websites as well. How could I accomplish this? What techniques could be used?

P.S. OAuth is not what I'm looking for as it works a bit differently. You still have to login using oath.

Answer (score 1):

This is called SSO (Single sign on).

You may use oAuth2 for this.
A possible scenario could be like this,

[image]

or, you may build your own following the strategy given in the diagram but oAuth2 gives you almost everything under the hood.

Comment: This answer describes OAuth 2.0 at a very high level with no details. This does not answer the question, how to do it. Plus this answer does not even cover SSO which is the first sentence of the answer.

Comment: I will cover in detail soon.
Thanks